# Submit a form and change the location of the frame that contains the frame, all at once

Tags: javascript, html

Problem: I have 2 frames, each with a form.  One frame is for navigation, the other is for 'doing stuff'

I want to click something in Frame A (Navigation frame)
and get the following behavior: 
1) Submit the form in Frame B (to save changes) 
2) Change the location of Frame B after saving changes (Navigate) 
3) Frame A should not submit/reload

So far, I can accomplish either of the above goals (1 or 2), but I can't save changes AND navigate in the same act.  I can get one or the other to work but I don't understand why.

Frame A (Navigation) uses code like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="return rowClicked(stuff)"> Navigate to Something </a>
```

Javascript for rowClicked:

```
top.frameB.document.getElementByID("frame_b_form_id").submit();
top.frameB.location="new location, so we can navigate";
return false; // Keeps frame A (Navigation) from reloading
```

My problem: If I don't change the location, my form in frame b submits and everything works perfectly.  But I want to navigate!  If I add the top.frameB.location javascript, the navigation works, but the form in the other frame doesn't get submitted!

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing!

EDIT:
This problem is in the latest Chrome and firefox browser versions ... This code seems to work as desired in IE 11, IE 8, FF 3.03

Last EDIT:
I never figured out how to do this consistently across browsers.  Fortunately, I realized that there was a better way to accomplish what I wanted.  The page was generated by mod_perl code, so 'submitting' the page caused not only the data saving, but also page re-generation (of the page the user was already on).  Navigating after that meant the server wasted time generating the page the user was navigating *away* from, on form submission.  The real fix was in my perl code so that a form submission triggered navigation ... I used javascript to add hidden inputs that were included with the form - the hidden inputs tell the server that after saving, generate a different page (ie navigate) and return that, instead of re-generating the page the user just visited & saved.

Comment: Do this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12499708/278405

Comment: That seems like it might have helped, but I did not use that.  I realized that my approach was all wrong - submitting, then navigating, doubled the work load for the server.  I added hidden inputs to the page before submitting, these told the server that after saving data, the new web page should be for a different 'location' (ie, after saving, navigate).  The html in question is dynamically generated via perl + mod_perl, so every submit equaled page generation.  Submit then change location = 2 page generations, only the second of which will get used (since the goal is navigation).