# Clear Form after submit to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have form which need to be submited to another domain, like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="https://example.com" target="myiframe" method="POST">

   <input type="text" name="email" value="">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="">
   <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

And iframe:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="myiframe" src=""></iframe>
```

This work fine, but after submit form it stays filled.
So, how to clear (reset) form after submit?

Comment: Did you try the onsubmit event?

Comment: I tried, I put in form onsubmit="clearFunction()"

Comment: Did it work for u? Shall i put it as an answer?

Comment: Nope,this will clear form before data is transfered

Comment: possible duplicate of [executing javascript after a form finishes submitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483016/executing-javascript-after-a-form-finishes-submitting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [event-listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to trigger the submit and the clearing.

First, change the submit button to a regular button with a proper id (you should do the same to the other elements):

```
<input type="button" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
```

Then bind the event-listener to the button with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function ()
    {
        handleTheForm;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Wherea `handleTheform` is a method, defined accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleTheForm()
    {
        document.forms[0].submit(); // Submit the form.
        document.forms[0].reset(); // Clear the form.
    }
</script>
```

**Edit** To handle the Enter button, simply add an event-listener for buttons and check which key is being pressed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e)
    {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var enterKey = 13;
        if (key == enterKey)
        {
            handleTheForm;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Your final picture should look something like this:**

```
<form id="myform" action="https://example.com" target="myiframe" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" />
  <input type="button" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleTheForm()
    {
        document.forms[0].submit(); // Submit the form.
        document.forms[0].reset(); // Clear the form.
    }

    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function ()
    {
        handleTheForm;
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e)
    {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var enterKey = 13;
        if (key == enterKey)
        {
            handleTheForm;
        }
    });
</script>
```

You might have to *tweek* something a little but since I haven't manage to test this.

Comment: Yea I was thinking about this but, I cannot do redirect because this url is used to get post data from bunch of places and must be like it's now.

Comment: I changed the concept to a more appropriate solution that should work for you.

Comment: Yeap, this onclick method will work. I tried exactly this and it works, but problem is that form will not work when someone hit "enter"

Comment: There's a special event-listener case for buttons. Look at my edit.

Comment: one more question before I accept answer. How I can add event-listener for enter just when cursor is focused in one of the form field. I don't want to submit form wherever hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499708/1257652) is applicable to your problem

```
// code from answer with bind() transfered to plain javascript
function SubmitWithCallback(form, frame, successFunction) {
   var callback = function () {
       if(successFunction)
           successFunction();
       frame.removeEventListener('load', callback, false);
   };

   frame.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
   form.submit();
}
```

Comment: From my understanding, the submit function is synchronous. It will submit first and then clear. Returning false will prevent multiple submits from occurring. I could be wrong, but I don't think so

Comment: @user3654631 - I found a simple solution that does what you are expecting. The function bind() just needs to be transferred from jQuery to plain javascript as an event handler

Comment: @user3654631 - I updated to plain javascript and removed the junk from my previous attempt. The implamentation would require onsubmit="SubmitWithCallback(document.myform, document.getElementById("myiframe"), this.clear);"  assuming you change the iframe to have an id of myiframe

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve this using **jQuery** by

```
$("#formId").reset();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Since `reset` is a native FormElement method, you'll first need to lose the jQuery object wrapping that form, i.e. `$('#formId')[0].reset()`;